# What is the equivalent of Valgrind within the Xcode environment?

Tags: xcode, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

It was recently recommended to me to use Valgrind to check for memory leaks, errors etc. on my iPhone project (which is written mainly in C and Objective-C).

I'm fairly new to this kind of work and was wondering what tools there were in Xcode that would serve the same purpose.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to check memory leaks then you can run your project with performance tool with leaks. Follow the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: See Davbid's response

Answer (score 7):

http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/iPhone_Simulator_Valgrind.20081224.html

Xcode's "Leaks" tool is not the same thing as Valgrind.  Valgrind detects overwriting memory boundaries  (amongst other things) in addition to detecting memory leaks.

Comment: Link is dead. What was the gist of the link?